# Add XML node without overwriting existing ones

Tags: xml, addition

I'm currently developing an speech recognition application using Microsoft Kinect SDK and the output should be a XML file following a certain structure, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Speech>
   <Item Words="hello" Confidence="0,5705749" Semantic="Child" />
   <Item Words="goodbye" Confidence="0,7705913" Semantic="Child" />
</Speech>
```

The Item node contains all the information read recognized the the Kinect's speech recognizer. The goal is: for each time it recognizes a new word, a new `<Item>` node is added along with its corresponding attributes.

I'm having issues with the update process, i.e., each time I add a new node, it overwrites the last one constantly ending up with only `<Item>` node. I've googled around and tried to apply the solutions from its search results but no success.

The function that writes the XML file is as follows:

```
 void WriteXML(string result, float confidence, string semantic, string typeOfSpeech)
 {
        try
        {
            //pick whatever filename with .xml extension
            string filename = "XML" + "SpeechOutput" + ".xml";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                xmlDoc.Load(filename);
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                //if file is not found, create a new xml file
                XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Speech");
                xmlWriter.Close();
                xmlDoc.Load(filename);
            }

            XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode lastWord = root.LastChild;

            XmlElement childNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Item");
            childNode.SetAttribute("Words", result);
            childNode.SetAttribute("Confidence", confidence.ToString());
            childNode.SetAttribute("Semantic", semantic);

            root.InsertAfter(childNode, lastWord);

            xmlDoc.Save("W:\\" + filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For easier testing, I'll add the code to a simpler App just to test this method:

```
namespace XMLTesting
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string typeOfSpeech;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WriteXML("test", 1, "semantic", "typeofspeech");
        WriteXML("test2", 2, "semantic", "typeofspeech");
    }

    void WriteXML(string result, float confidence, string semantic, string typeOfSpeech)
    {
        try
        {
            //pick whatever filename with .xml extension
            string filename = "XML" + "SpeechOutput" + ".xml";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                xmlDoc.Load(filename);
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                //if file is not found, create a new xml file
                XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Speech");
                xmlWriter.Close();
                xmlDoc.Load(filename);
            }

            XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode lastWord = root.LastChild;

            XmlElement childNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Item");
            childNode.SetAttribute("Words", result);
            childNode.SetAttribute("Confidence", confidence.ToString());
            childNode.SetAttribute("Semantic", semantic);

            root.InsertAfter(childNode, lastWord);

            xmlDoc.Save("W:\\" + filename);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    void WriteError(string str)
    {
        //outputBox.Text = str;
    }
}
```

}

The output file of this application is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Speech>
 <Item Words="test2" Confidence="2" Semantic="semantic" />
</Speech>
```

Instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Speech>
    <Item Words="test" Confidence="1" Semantic="semantic" />
    <Item Words="test2" Confidence="2" Semantic="semantic" />
  </Speech>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me and adds a new line at the end of the file for every call of `WriteXml`. Where and how do you call the method? Is this method the only one that writes to the XML destination file?

Comment: I'm calling the method on a method called spRecEng_SpeechRecognized() which in turn is called whenever the Speech Recognition app recognizes a given speech. I thought I'd give it a try also and test this WriteXML() method in a very simple application (which I'll be adding now to the original post) and it still didn't work...

Comment: The sample application works as expected! I have two lines in the generated XML.

Answer (score 0):

If using the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is a necessity, then i could suggest some enhancements:

- don't use exceptions to check if the file exists or not. Use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- if the file does not exist, create it. Then the load operation should always work (if the file was created successfully) and you will need only one load operation
- define the full file name (name + location) only once and use it everywhere. This should reduce the errors when trying to access (read or write) the file.

The slightly modified `WriteXml` (that works for me):

```
void WriteXML(string result, float confidence, string semantic, string typeOfSpeech)
{
    try
    {
        //pick whatever filename with .xml extension
        string filename = Path.Combine("W:\\", "XMLSpeechOutput.xml");

        //if file is not found, create a new xml file
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {           
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Speech");
            xmlWriter.Close();
        }
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(filename);
        XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode lastWord = root.LastChild;

        XmlElement childNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Item");
        childNode.SetAttribute("Words", result);
        childNode.SetAttribute("Confidence", confidence.ToString());
        childNode.SetAttribute("Semantic", semantic);

        root.InsertAfter(childNode, lastWord);

        xmlDoc.Save(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteError(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

If it is alright for you to use another technology to access / modify the XML structure, then i suggest you to use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) - for the current problem, the usage will reduce the lines of code.  My example contains two extension methods:

- the first is to *create* or *open* the specified XML file (if the file does not exists, an empty file is created)
- the second appends a row at the end of the XML file

The extensions code:

```
public static class ProjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the file with the specified name.
    /// If the file does not exist an empty file is created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlFile">File location with name: c:\xml\input.xml</param>
    /// <returns>A filled XDocument object</returns>
    public static XDocument CreateOrLoad(this String xmlFile)
    {
        // if the XML file does not exist
        if (!File.Exists(xmlFile))
        {
            // create an empty file
            var emptyXml = new XElement("Speech");
            // and save it under the specified name (and location)
            emptyXml.Save(xmlFile);         
        }
        // load the file (it was either created or it exists already)
        return XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds new row at the end of the specified XML document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">TODO</param>
    /// <param name="confidence">TODO</param>
    /// <param name="semantic">TODO</param>
    public static void AppendRow(this XDocument document, string result, float confidence, string semantic, string typeOfSpeech)
    {
        // prepare/construct the row to add
        var row = new XElement("Item",  new XAttribute("Word", result),
                                        new XAttribute("Precision", confidence.ToString()),
                                        new XAttribute("Semantic", semantic));
        // take the root node
        var root = document.Root;
        // the xml is empty
        if (!root.Elements().Any())
        {
            // just add the node
            root.Add(row);
        }
        else
        {
            // add the node after at the end of the file
            root.Elements().Last().AddAfterSelf(row);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
var filename = "W:\\XMLSpeechOut.xml";
//
var xml = filename.CreateOrLoad();
xml.AppendRow("A", 10.5f, "B", "C");
xml.AppendRow("D", 11.0f, "E", "F");
xml.Save(filename);
// alternative one-liner usage (open or create, append, save)
filename.CreateOrLoad().AppendRow("G", 11.5f, "H", "I").Save(filename);
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Speech>
  <Item Word="A" Precision="10,5" Semantic="B" />
  <Item Word="D" Precision="11" Semantic="E" />
  <Item Word="G" Precision="11,5" Semantic="H" />
</Speech>
```